# Countdown asp using VBS

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a Countdown Page, it shall show each counted number, it takes the numbers from a user entry, inside a table.

In the end it shall show for example from 10 to 1, the numbers 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.

Meanwhile i get Results, but only for counting up, but how do i get it to count down, it goes into my loop but it shows only the first Number, how do i display the rest?

```
          <%
response.flush
l_start = request.querystring("f_start")
l_goal = request.querystring("f_goal")


%>

<form action = "countdown.asp" method = "get">
   <h1 align = "center">Dies ist ein Zähler!<h1>
    <table border = "1" align = "center">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Bitte einen Startwert eingeben.
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type = "number" name = "f_start" value = "<%=l_start%>"
        </td>
        <td width = "100">
          &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          Bitte einen Zielwert eingeben.
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type = "number" name = "f_goal" value = "<%=l_goal%>"
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type = "submit" value = "Go!" \>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Gez&auml;hlte Zahlen:
        </td>
        <td>
          <%
            if request.querystring(("f_start")) < request.querystring(("f_goal")) then
              For i = l_start To l_goal
                response.write("" & i & ",")
              Next
            else
                counter = l_start
              while counter > l_goal
                response.write(counter)
                response.write(",")
                counter = l_start - 1
              wend
            end if
          %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here. First, you only go into the `then` clause of the `if` statement if `f_start` is greater then `f_goal`, then you only go into the body of the `while` if `f_start` is less than or equal to `f_goal`. The conditions are similar for the `else` clause.

But it's worse than that because you use variables called `f_start`, `f_goal` and `f_count` that aren't defined. I think you intend to use values from `Request.QueryString`, but that's not what you're doing.

You assign values to `l_start`, `l_goal` and `l_count` but never change them. You modify the values in `x` and `y` but never use them. You put the unchanged `l_start` and `l_goal` back into the form.

Finally, there appears to be a cognitive disconnect in your understanding of where this code executes and how the variables in the script are related to the form. This is executing on the server. The values you enter in the form get submitted to the server. The script runs and does not do anything with the values passed to it from the form. It then puts those values right back onto the form.

Comment: Actually, your last part is incorrect. OP did not put `runat="server"` in the script tag, so it runs **on the client side**. Modern browsers, even [Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx) will just ignore it.

Comment: So you mean the if is unnescesary or even wrong? And f_goal, f_start should be definded by a user entry. –

Comment: I saw the asp-classic tag on the question and made the assumption the script was running on the server. Sorry about that. Rex, I can't help you further than I have. The fact that this script runs on the client (assuming you're using Internet Explorer and assuming you've turned on its options to execute vbscript) makes it worse.

Comment: It was helpfull enough now i'm a big step closer to my goal, but i'm stil not fully there.